# Python: Find corresponding elements in a list and sum them up in a new list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings where the first part of the string is a substring of other elements in the list. 
I aim to find all similar strings i.e elements with the 'ID_1' substring, add them to a list and then sum up their respective values after the "=".

Example:

```
start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
```

I've tried iterating over start_list with for loops, created various nested lists and even tried dictionaries but I keep going in circles.

I know there is an elegant solution somewhere.

The output I expect is:

```
ID_1 = 6
ID_2 = 15
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please also post your code as instructed in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that this is your 1st question my approach is trying to be as simple and straightfoward as I can and put many comments to explain in detail every step.

While providing more complex or pythonic code would be a better solution it could end in giving you code that you cannot easily understand or customize on your own.

```
start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
print start_list

# Here I am preparing an empty dictionary to store the counted keys and values
counted = {}
# Now I iterate through every string in start_list
for item in start_list:
    # As 1st thing I will use split method to separate the current_key
    current_key = item.split("=")[0]
    # and the current value. 
    current_value = int(item.split("=")[1])
    # Then I check if current_key (e.g. ID_1) is present in the
    # count dictionary using "in"
    if current_key in counted:
        # If the key is present I update its value with the sum
        # of its old value + new one
        counted[current_key] = current_value + counted[current_key]
    else:
        # If the key doesn't exist it means that we are adding it
        # to the counted dictionary for the 1st time
        counted[current_key] = current_value 

# Job is done!
print counted

# It is now easy to iterate through counted dict for further manipulation
# for example let's print the number of hits for ID_1

# You can use items() to enumerate keys and values in a dictionary
for key, value in counted.items():
    if key == "ID_1":
        print("Found ID_1 value: " + str(value))

# To obtain the output in your requirement
for key in counted.keys():
    print( '%s = %d' %(key, counted[key]))
```

If you want to know more about how the split method works here's a nice explanation and examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

In other answers you will find more concise and pythonic ways to obtain this result.

Therefore, in order to improve the code I wrote I would suggest you to read more about list comprehensions here:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Comment: Thank you for this. I really appreciate you going through each line, much appreciated.

Comment: I am glad you liked the answer, @LachlanGray.
If it was useful for you please remember to upvote it and / or choose it as an answer :)

Comment: Hi Pitto. Please refrain from adding "happy hacking" or other sign-offs - technical writing is preferred here. I can provide from references from _Meta_ on request.

Comment: Hi @halfer and thanks for your edit. Please share the references so I can read and improve my answers, thanks!

Comment: [This editing advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) is probably the canonical one. [This article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) is in a similar vein, and argues for brevity. This one [is from the over-Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in an elegant way using `groupby` from `itertools`

```
l = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
l_2 = sorted(x.split('=') for x in l)
from itertools import groupby

ans = [(k, sum(int(y) for x,y in g))
       for k,g in  groupby(l_2, key=lambda x: x[0])]

for key, value in ans:
    print(key, '=', value)
```

Other elegant solutions can be to use defaultdict or reduce

Be aware that is O(nlog(n)) solution because you need to sort the list

Comment: I like the `groupby` approach, but be sure to `sort` the list first by the same key (it already is, but this might not always be the case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this. I found it most compact and correct variant.

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']

d = defaultdict(int)
lst = [item.split('=') for item in start_list]
for k, v in lst:
    d[k] += int(v)

print(d.items())
```

**Output:**

```
dict_items([('ID_1', 6), ('ID_2', 15)])
```

You can iterate over `d.items` to print data in required format.

**Code:**

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"{k}={v}")
```

**Output:**

```
ID_1=6
ID_2=15
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `collections.Counter` to keep track of the sums. Combined with `functools.reduce` you could even make this a one-liner if you like:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
>>> reduce(lambda c, x: c.update({x[0]: int(x[1])}) or c,
...        (x.split("=") for x in start_list), collections.Counter())
...
Counter({'ID_1': 6, 'ID_2': 15})
```

(Here, `or c` makes the `lambda` return `c` instead of the result of `update`, which is `None`)

Answer (score 0):

```
start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
dict = {}

for item in start_list:
    k = item.split('=')[0]
    if k in dict.keys():
        dict[k] = int(dict[k])+int(item.split('=')[1])
    else:
        dict.update({k:int(item.split('=')[1])})

print (dict) # {'ID_1': 6, 'ID_2': 15}

for key,val in dict.items():
    print ("{} = {}".format(key,val))
```

output:

```
ID_1 = 6
ID_2 = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension + a dictionary comprehension:

```
start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
l = [i.split('=') for i in start_list]
d = dict(l)
print({k:sum([int(i[1]) for i in l if i[0] == k]) for k,v in d.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'ID_1': 6, 'ID_2': 15}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that your data always have the same format then you can just iterate over the list and then create a dictionary to hold the result:

```
start_list = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']
result = {}

for item in start_list:
    id, value = item.split('=')
    # Create new key, value if key is not in 'result' dict, sum up if it does exists
    result[id] = int(value) if not result.get(id) else (int(value) + result[id])

print(result) # {'ID_2': 15, 'ID_1': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
l = ['ID_1=1', 'ID_1=2', 'ID_1=3', 'ID_2=4', 'ID_2=5', 'ID_2=6']

def calculate_score_byid(s):
    '''takes a list of items and adds up scores. returns a dictionary of scores'''
    d = dict()
    for i in l:
        if i.split('=')[0] not in d.keys():
            d[i.split('=')[0]]=int(i.split('=')[1])
        else:
            d[i.split('=')[0]]=int(d[i.split('=')[0]])+int(i.split('=')[1])
    return d

calculate_score_byid(l)
for key in d.keys():
    print( '%s = %d' %(key,d[key]))

>>>ID_1 = 6
>>>ID_2 = 15
```